# Как задать свои css для классов колонок в Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть код:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div id="a" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Хочу чтобы при изменении разрешения экрана, менялся цвет #a

```
#a{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
#a.col-xs-12{
    background-color: green;
}
#a.col-md-4{
    background-color: red;
}
#a.col-lg-3{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

#a всегда окрашивается в синий.
Как исправить?

Comment: 2alvoro:
Спасибо.

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #a{
   background-color: red!important;
   }
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибка - для `#a` всегда будут применяться стили #a.col-xs-12, #a.col-md-4 и #a.col-lg-3. Что бы реализовать то, что вы задумали, я предлагаю вам использовать [media query](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198292/)